# Are philosophers' contributions to computer science overlooked?

Tags: philosophy-of-computer-science

George Boole's work on Boolean logic is a basic foundational part of computer science, Bertrand Russell's work was influential on data types, Ludwig Wittgenstein invented truth tables, logical positivists were obsessed with classifying everything in the world as either true or false, Charles Sanders Pierce noticed that logical operations could be performed by electronically switching currents, and object-oriented programming has been compared by many to Plato's study of forms, although I have no idea if its inventors were actually influenced by it.

It simply struck me as odd to see so many philosophers involved in foundational work in something that is not typically associated with philosophy. I myself see computer science and programming as a positively philosophical endeavor. Programmers create a purely abstract, synthetic implementation to solve a real world problem in an environment, that scales through abstraction levels ranging from electronic logic gates and binary representations of numbers and data, to more highly abstracted data types, finally weaving through a complex and dynamic interaction of countless variables in some electronic playground we have created out of our own collective imaginations, that then has to eventually produce output that somehow winds up being useful in the real world.

If that's not philosophy at work, then I believe I must be misunderstanding what philosophy is all about.

Comment: George Boole: Ok, Russell: partial. Wuttgenstein, Peirce, Logical Positivism: no real contribution at all to the development of Compter Science. The "founding fathers" (after some pionners, like Leibniz and Boole and Babbage) where Alan Turing and John von Neumann.

Comment: See Martin Davis, [The Universal Computer: The Road from Leibniz to Turing](https://books.google.it/books?id=azXSBQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Somewhere here there is a question about philosophy and artificial intelligence. Might be relevant.

Comment: The history of computer science before [Presper Eckert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._Presper_Eckert) and [John Mauchley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Mauchly) often pays a fast tribute to thinkers going back to the [Antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism), however, computer science is mostly interested in the birth and development of digital computers. If you're a computer science student, you certainly can learn a lot from the evolution of the Western Canon.

Comment: I must say that I believe that truth tables are a huge foundational part of Computer Science.  In fact, the entire world is nothing more than a complex interaction of truth tables.

Comment: @AbercrombieDorfen Suggestions of the nature of the world as a deterministic state machine long predates ideas such as truth tables or state machines. Their origin is more tightly tied to the idea of atheism.

Comment: @Guy Inchbald  That may be, except truth table are taught to every Computer Science student in foundational courses and Wittgenstein is typically credited as their inventor.

Comment: @AbercrombieDorfen Yes indeed. But it was not me who suggested that Wittgenstein had nothing to do with it. If I were to challenge your view it would be on the basis of quantum indeterminacy, an area where few philosophers have any authority.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I think that perspective about the irrelevance of logical positivism is ignoring its influence on Godel, who set a lot of groundwork up for Turing. Also, no mention of Alonso Church?

Comment: @AbercrombieDorfen And to me, truth tables are something completely unnecessary and utterly clumsy.

Comment: Why the hostility of computer people to philosophy, not wanting to give philosophers like Russell any credit for computational device development? I have noticed over the years the poor quality of texts from computer scientists, ie some lack in grasp of humanists' skills.

Comment: Scholars and religions pondered over the end game for the story of humanity. Besides Armageddon, they seemed to be lost in uncertainty about what the overall purpose and the end game for humanity would look like. The future of computer science showed us the way, maybe for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

The situation is clouded because figures such as Leibnitz were both great mathematicians and great philosophers. Moreover Leibnitz once wrote how

> "In imagining that there is a machine whose construct­ion would enable it to think, to sense, and to have perception, one could conceive it enlarged while retaining the same pro­portions, so that one could enter into it, just like into a mill. Supposing this, one should, when visiting within it, find only parts pushing one another, and never any­thing by which to explain a perception.
>
> "Thus each organic body of a living being is a kind of divine machine or natural automaton which infinitely sur­passes all artificial automata."

A remarkable vision of an AI which can pass the Turing test, from the man who beat Newton to the calculus.
And yes, I think it fair to say that Leibnitz' philosophical contribution to AI has been overlooked.

Indeed the key social issues of AI (currently little more than Machine Learning + Big Data) such as censorship, privacy, propaganda and personal safety are as much part of moral philosophy as anything else. As and when we start arguing whether Leibnitz was right or wrong and is a given Turing-competent AI therefore sentient, philosophy will truly return to computer science with a vengeance.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't think so. Boolean logic and truth tables aren't that complicated, given enough time really anybody could come up with similar logic. It was just inevitable that at some point someone actually did it, and someone else called it 'philosophy'.

But were these people fundamental to computer science and modern computer hardware? Not really. Modern computing, in my opinion, is likely the result of the contributions of probably hundreds of thousands of different people from all walks of life over the past millennia. You can't really pin a significant chunk of it to a few philosophers, or philosophy more broadly.

Comment: Counterfactuals are subtle and innovations are sometimes “in the air”; but it does seem possible we might be in a significantly different place without some very specific insights from Leibniz and Boole and Frege…?

Comment: It's all obvious in hindsight. Even algebra. But humanity waits centuries for someone to come all along and invent it. Algebra is ancient BC. So is logic. But it took till the 19th century for someone to come up with "Boolean Algebra".

Answer (score 0):

#### The Connection

**The relationship between computer science and philosophy is strong conceptually.** This is because computer science has two aspects, the very rational and mathematical theory that computer scientists study, and the very empirical and engineering-oriented praxis which inspires and reinforces the theory. Both of these aspects rest on the Western canon of philosophy. And, computer science, in this way, has two personalities, and famous computer scientists often embody both forms of expertise.

Consider the father of computer science, [Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing). Turing was a mathematician by training; his PhD thesis is a logic. His mathematical skills were beyond question. But he is also very famous for his [SigInit work at Bletchley Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bletchley_Park#Work_on_specific_countries%27_signals). **Clearly, Turing was both a theoretician and an engineer of the finest caliber**.

**Another example is Donald Knuth whose work on algorithms is famous.** His [*The Art of Computer Programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) is a bible of sorts. This thinker was also responsible for [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) whose extensions are famous for typesetting, particularly among mathematicians and computer scientists.

#### Computer Science and Philosophy

**But the discipline of computer science devotes very little energy to philosophy as a whole.** In fact, if you search for philosophy of computer science books, you'll find your options rather impoverished. On the short list is:

- Colburn's [*Philosophy and Computer Science (2015)* (GB)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_and_Computer_Science/w5xzCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)
- Turner's [*Computational Artifacts: Towards a Philosophy of Computer Science (2018)*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Computational_Artifacts/QNNjDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)
- Rapaport's [*Philosophy of Computer Science: An Introduction to the Issues and the Literature* (2023)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_of_Computer_Science/_KujEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=philosophy%20of%20computer%20science&printsec=frontcover)

**There is also some philosophical work adjacent to computer science** such as [Floridi](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Philosophy_and_Computing/eiSEAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=philosophy%20of%20computer%20science&printsec=frontcover) who is interested in the philosophy of information and computation and has a [semantic account of information (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/information-semantic/), [Piccinini](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Physical_Computation/780kCQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) who is has syntactic account of [physical computation (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computation-physicalsystems/), and [Shagrir](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Nature_of_Physical_Computation/HfhQEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) who has his semantic account of physical computation.

One place where philosophy and computer science is strongly connected is the [philosophy of artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence). Margaret Boden and the Churchlands are contributors to literature about the topic. Of course, this is strongly animated by interest in the philosophy of mind.

#### Historical Contributions

**Part of the reason of the disconnect between computer scientists and philosophers is that computer science is a young discipline.** Part of it seems to be a very pragmatic focus of computer scientists on building cool stuff. LLMs are the recent example of a fascinating trend for computer science to produce cutting edge technology that challenges our philosophical notions. And lastly, there is no clear dividing line between mathematics, logic, and computer science, as the [Curry-Howard Correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) attests. Thus the philosophy of computer science blends into the philosophies of mathematics and logic. That isn't readily apparent to people not familiar with the deeper recess of computer science theory.

You ask:

> Are philosophers' contributions to computer science overlooked?

**So, yes and no.** Computer scientists often don't receive any formal training in philosophy, and it's sort of a niche intersectionality that those interested in AI and AGI pursue. Historically, it's not part of Academia's curricula very broadly. But the actual philosophers themselves, of course, are widely studied. Boole and Leibniz, for instance are well known. Pierce is a rather unique figure in US philosophers with a very empirical perspective of computation. Philosophers of science of all stripes play prominently in the hard scientific aspects of building computers. **But there's no doubt that philosophy of computer science is a very brand new community of scholars in opposition to communities of philosophers of mathematics, physics, or logic.**